# Shouldn't Terry's younger brother have the same genetic traits as him?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited, batman-beyond

In the final Justice League Unlimited episode *Epilogue* Waller reveals this about Terry

> Waller: Your father thought he was getting a flu shot. Actually it was a nano-tech solution programmed to rewrite his reproductive material into an exact copy of Bruce Wayne's. A little over a year later, your mother gave birth to you. A child sharing half her genetic material, and half Bruce's.

Shouldn't Matt McGinnis (the younger brother) also be like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quote from Bruce Timm that Matt is also a child / clone of Bruce Wayne.

> Bruce Timm on "Epilogue” #1:  “Well, we didn’t come right out and say it, but since Warren’s love gun was shooting 'Bruce Wayne bullets,' yes, Matt is also Bruce’s biological son. - http://jl.toonzone.net/episode50/episode50.htm

Unfortunately I can't find a more credible source to that quote.

**It has also been pointed out that both Terry and Matt have black hair, while their parents have light brown and red hair. Bruce Wayne has black hair.**

Answer (score 6):

**Not necessarily.** It would make far more sense to simply edit the DNA sequencing of a limited period of the father's spermatozoa than it would be to completely rewrite his entire DNA sequence of his entire body.

Since they would not want evidence of this tampering, the nanites would likely perform their duties for a time and then self-destruct and exit the body, leaving no permanent trace of their having been there.

The only reason the younger brother would have similar DNA options was if the program wanted there to be a spare...

Comment: I can't recall where I read this (hence not adding this as an answer),  but Matt *was* supposed to be a backup in case Terry didn't work out.

Comment: Ewwwwww. Nasty people.

Comment: Well it's Project Cadmus. They're not exactly into ponies and fluffy bunny rabbits.

Comment: I have never understood why that place wasn't EVER shut down. There was always one atrocity or another coming out of it

Comment: And knowing Project Cadmus, if they were, they would be stylishly colored, nuclear-powered, genetically-enhanced ponies and mega-fluffy, telepathic vorpal bunnies capable of removing organs without disturbing the surrounding flesh. Designed for the discriminating super-villain or evil corporate CEO.